# Pulseaudio does not find my docking station's audio

Tags: linux, debian, alsa, udev

Short: my updated pulseaudio does not find the USB audio device of my docking station.

Debian Stretch, XPS 13 9360, docking station WD15.
I just built pulseaudio from source, and got this version:

```
$ pulseaudio --version
pulseaudio 12.0-304-gb89d3
```

I cloned the project in order to get the latest drivers. There was a [solution](https://github.com/edrose/dell-dock-audio-fix) posted on github, but was apparently [obsoleted](https://github.com/edrose/dell-dock-audio-fix/issues/2) by an update of pulseaudio. I do have the [fixing commit 60c0edd](https://github.com/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/commit/60c0edd5286dbb731c671ad3e6886c1e3e1eb067) in my local git clone, which I built and installed system-wise.

Strange things:

1. somehow, the install did not copy the conf file to my system. I did that manually, to `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets`. Am I correct in my beliefs that the copy is needed, and that the install should have done it? I followed the system install instructions [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/PulseAudioFromGit/).
2. I restarted pulseaudio with `pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start`. I checked my USB devices and got:

.

```
$ lsusb | grep 0bda
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:4014 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

The second row is what is described in the udev rule file `/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules`, which was installed with pulseaudio:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bda", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4014", ENV{PULSE_PROFILE_SET}="dell-dock-tb16-usb-audio.conf"
```

After this, I expect alsamixer to find my dock's audio. It doesn't.

Instead, it finds the local laptop sound device, and something on USB, called `USB Audio`, which has only one field: loudness.

How do I make sure that the USB device in `lsusb` gets detected correctly by pulseaudio? Was I wrong when I copied the conf file?

---

EDIT: I do get sound when I run this:

```
aplay -D plughw:CARD=1,DEV=0 /usr/share/sounds/speech-dispatcher/test.wav
```

---

EDIT2:
Apparently my USB card (the dock) is recognized as a Generic USB:

```
$ udevadm info -qall -p /sys/class/sound/card1
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.5/3-1.5:1.0/sound/card1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:39:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.5/3-1.5:1.0/sound/card1
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=sound-pci-0000_39_00_0-usb-0_1_5_1_0
E: ID_ID=usb-Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001-00
E: ID_MODEL=USB_Audio
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Audio
E: ID_MODEL_ID=4014
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:39:00.0-usb-0:1.5:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_39_00_0-usb-0_1_5_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=0005
E: ID_SERIAL=Generic_USB_Audio_200901010001
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=200901010001
E: ID_TYPE=audio
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=snd-usb-audio
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:010100:010200:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=Generic
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Generic
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0bda
E: PULSE_PROFILE_SET=dell-dock-tb16-usb-audio.conf
E: SOUND_INITIALIZED=1
E: SUBSYSTEM=sound
E: SYSTEMD_WANTS=sound.target
E: TAGS=:systemd:seat:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=482209651377
```

Comment: Did you resolve that issue by any chance? I have same issue now, after firmware upgrade on dell dock.

Comment: @koper89 Yes, with a debian upgrade to buster. I couldn't make alsamixer to work, but pavucontrol and pacmd do, and in fine with it.